# Unity gone after updating 16.10 - Boots into Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

A few months ago I installed Gnome on my Ubuntu 15.10, 15 minutes later I decided to remove and revert back to Unity.
I didn't remember how I removed Gnome but I remember reading from AskUbuntu and after uninstalling Gnome the boot animation remained. I didn't mind it.

Last night after a few unsuccessful "do-release-upgrade" attempts to update my ubuntu laptop 16.04 to 16.10, I decided partially update the whole system (package by package) throughout the whole day, I successfully logged into 16.10 but not into unity, gnome. I checked the little box on login screen options to select unity.

What Should I do to start using my ubuntu 16.10 with Unity. I got a few customizations on unity configuration, it would be really cool to keep them intact while reverting if possible.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unity is either broken, or was uninstalled. You *may or may not* be able to keep your customization options. I doubt it, as you were manually upgrading to 16.10 (which I *do not recommend*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and run following command to reset unity:

```
unity --reset
```

Does it work? If no, you could try reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`

Run following command one-by-one :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Reboot may necessary

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: unity reset throws "deprecated" warning.
But reinstalling ubuntu-desktop solved my problem.
All customizations aren't changed.

Comment: I'm very glad it worked.